# PHP PDO securety

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I had created an PHP-Object for my Database, and now i have a question is it protected from SQL-Injections??? Here my method to load Data form Database

```
public function loadData($query, $params = []) {
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

My Query

```
$user_id = trim($_GET['user']);
$article_id = trim($_GET['article']);

$data = loadData("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE user = ? AND article = ?", [$user_id, $article_id]);
```

or this solution.

```
$myData = [$user_id, $article_id];

$data = loadData("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE user = ? AND article = ?", $myData);
```

Comment: Both options come out exactly the same, no difference.

Comment: A hint: make your function return $stmt. It will keep the current functionality but also will make this function  a lot more useful.

Comment: They are exactly the same options, but you shouldn't access $_GET directly.

Comment: My question was, is it secure enough to prevent SQL-Injection. Thank you

Comment: What is not clear from the linked answer? thanks.